# Select all items Where cat_id= x or parent_id = x (Parent id different table)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi as the title say i have a php code where i sucefully echo the articles in a table, the problem is in this table i just have cat_id the parent_id is referenced in other table..

```
"articulos" table

id | titulo | fecha_evento | descripcion | img | cat_id

"categoriablog" table

    id | parent_id
```

This is the way im making my query

```
$query1 = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha_evento,descripcion,img FROM articulos WHERE cat_id = 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);
```

My goal is to do something like this, but "parent_id" is in other table

```
$query1 = "SELECT id,titulo,fecha_evento,descripcion,img FROM articulos WHERE cat_id = 1 OR parent_id = 1";
        $result = mysql_query($query1);
```

Comment: As ever: _please_, for your sake and the rest of the world's: _stop using the `mysql_*` extension_. It's been deprecated, and bount to be removed at some point in the not-too-distant future. Well, it should've been removed ages ago, but anyway: [read the read box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect) at the top of the page, and clikc the links to learn about the alternatives (`PDO` and `mysqli_*`)

Comment: Thanks for the info, i just find out that yesterday, sorry about this, ill promess i will study PDO and mysqli so i can move on , and update myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, a.titulo, a.fecha_evento, a.descripcion, a.img 
FROM Article AS a 
INNER JOIN Category AS c ON a.cat_id = c.id
WHERE a.cat_id = x
   OR c.parent_id = x
```

Comment: I get a mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource. i do understand the name of tables must be changed, but i do not understand the a.cat_id stuff

Comment: @MonchoChavez - `a` and `c` are called aliases, instead of writing the whole name all over the query, they are used as a short names, you can remove them and use the full names instead. It should work fine, Can you please show what is the error you got. Have you tried it directly on mysql?

Comment: Yes thank you.. mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Comment: @MonchoChavez - It might be your query is not valid, please check the `mysql_query` return value, if it's false, check `mysql_error()`. Please edit your question and show these results and the exact query you tried, Have you tried your query directly in MySQL?

Comment: I havent, i will, the error is this "Fatal error: Query failed: Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous in"

Comment: @MonchoChavez - OK, Sorry, add the alias to the selected column, see my edit.

Comment: Wow , know i also understand more that code, thanks and i promess (for the guy who downvote) that i will left the use of mysql_query XD jajaja, thanks for your open and comprensive mind.

Comment: @MonchoChavez - You're welcome any time :) Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query

```
SELECT id,titulo,fecha_evento,descripcion,img FROM Article
 WHERE cat_id = 1 OR cat_id IN
 (SELECT id from Category where parent_id=1)
```

**Edit**

Please note that this solution is a little bit slower than the JOIN solution in the answer by Mahmoud.

Comment: Maybe its faster , but your answer is at my userlevel , i can understand it quite well, jaja , anyway i will try to use Mahmoud solution , if its faster, the problem is i got errors cause i do not understand what im doing actually on his query, i just have an idea, thanks

Comment: Your approach towards programming is very good because of the fact that you are really trying to understand the answers you are getting and also trying to use the better one. This approach will help you along the way and make you a good programmer